# How to repeat values by assigning them to a different time step

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a dataframe with different time steps:

```
Dataframe 1 :
02/06/2021 17:57   /    16.38 
02/06/2021 18:05   /    25.89
02/06/2021 18:11   /    21.32
02/06/2021 18:32   /    12.65
02/06/2021 19:00   /    14.78
...                    ....
```

I would like to put the same value for every minute between steps, like this:

```
02/06/2021 17:57    /   16.38
02/06/2021 17:58    /   16.38
02/06/2021 17:59    /   16.38
02/06/2021 18:00    /   16.38
02/06/2021 18:01    /   16.38
02/06/2021 18:02    /   16.38
02/06/2021 18:03    /   16.38
02/06/2021 18:04    /   16.38 
02/06/2021 18:05    /   25.89 
02/06/2021 18:06    /   25.89
02/06/2021 18:07    /   25.89
02/06/2021 18:08    /   25.89
02/06/2021 18:09    /   25.89
02/06/2021 18:10    /   25.89
02/06/2021 18:11    /   21.32
02/06/2021 18:12    /   21.32
...etc
```

I guess it's a "while" loop, but I'm new to info and I'm having trouble getting through it.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `complete` and `fill` will be helpful here -

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(datetime = dmy_hm(datetime)) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = '1 min')) %>%
  fill(value)

#   datetime            value
#   <dttm>              <dbl>
# 1 2021-06-02 17:57:00  16.4
# 2 2021-06-02 17:58:00  16.4
# 3 2021-06-02 17:59:00  16.4
# 4 2021-06-02 18:00:00  16.4
# 5 2021-06-02 18:01:00  16.4
# 6 2021-06-02 18:02:00  16.4
# 7 2021-06-02 18:03:00  16.4
# 8 2021-06-02 18:04:00  16.4
# 9 2021-06-02 18:05:00  25.9
#10 2021-06-02 18:06:00  25.9
# … with 54 more rows
```

It is not clear what is the format of your date. I have assumed your data is in `dmy` format, if you have dates in `mdy` format then use `mdy_hm` function.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(datetime = c("02/06/2021 17:57   ", "02/06/2021 18:05   ", 
"02/06/2021 18:11   ", "02/06/2021 18:32   ", "02/06/2021 19:00   "
), value = c(16.38, 25.89, 21.32, 12.65, 14.78)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Interesting..
You're right, my format is this one in R :  2021-06-02 17:57:15 (I guess ymd_hms).
When I try it, the program returns the statement: Error in UseMethod("fill_") : 
  no method for 'fill_' applicable for an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Here is my code : 
`DF=read.csv2("C:.....csv", sep=";", header=TRUE, dec = ",")
DF$Pentes=as.numeric(DF$Pentes)

DF %>%
    mutate(DF$Timestamp = ymd_hms(DF$Timestamp)) %>%
  complete(DF$Timestamp = seq(min(DF$Timestamp), max(DF$Timestamp), by = '1 min')) %>%
  fill(DF$Pentes)`

So I give to the function fill a vector right? I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: Oh right, I understand. I think it's working, thank you very much.
Sorry, I am a real beginner. Bye